# Wifi issues on Elementary

Tags: dual-boot

I am not very familiar with Linux OS. I just installed elementary on my Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro Win 10.  I have 2 issues:
1. Boot option screen: you could hardly read it the options, very small characters???
2. Can't connect to internet? I don't even see or know from where to start?
Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Elementary using your wifi? I am new to Linux too and had an issue with connecting to the internet after installing it using my wifi. It showed up in Edit connections but I could not choose it as an option.
I solved it by using an Ethernet connection to connect to the internet (wired connection) and doing all the updates (a bit over 500 for system updates). After that the wifi showed up on the connections but did not give me an option to switch to it from wired. 
It wasn't until I installed the **optional** update for Broadcom 802.11 Linux Sta wireless driver source (wifi driver) that it showed up in connections and I was able to turn wired off and choose wifi and then I connected without a problem.

Comment: Hi Kim, the WiFi was working fine before the installation. As you mentioned, after installation I couldn’t get connected not I could see an option to choose WiFi. I got wired connection, installed all updates but the issue remains!!! How did You install the optional drive for Broadcom and where did get it from. Cheers

Comment: After the last update started it showed up in the list of updates (in App center) as an optional update. (free) and I installed it last. Maybe you can use your wired connection and go into App center and search for an updated wifi driver? It found mine, I had no idea what I had for wifi driver as this was my brother's old laptop which has windows that doesn't work right, and my first time using it.